# CentOS as a router -- Can't get static IP adress for Internal Zone

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, ip, router, dhcp

I'm trying to make a router with a CentOS 7 box.

enp2s2f0 ---> External Zone ---> directly connected to the internet.
enp2s2f1 ---> Internal Zone ---> Connected to a PC (will be connected to a switch in the future)

See my actual ifconfig result :

```
[root@localhost ~]# ifconfig
enp2s2f0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::216:35ff:fe5c:913a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2a01:e35:2e02:90f0:216:35ff:fe5c:913a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 00:16:35:5c:91:3a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 255  bytes 25694 (25.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 191  bytes 25734 (25.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 25  

enp2s2f1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::216:35ff:fe5c:9139  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:16:35:5c:91:39  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 54  bytes 5486 (5.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10  bytes 1644 (1.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 26  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

My interfaces config files :

enp2s2f0

```
HWADDR="00:16:35:5C:91:3A"
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
ONBOOT="yes"
ZONE="external"
```

enp2s2f1

```
HWADDR="00:16:35:5C:91:39"
TYPE="Bridge"
BOOTPROTO="static"
ONBOOT="yes"
IPADDR="10.100.0.1"
NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
```

DHCPD config file :

```
ddns-update-style interim;

allow booting;
allow bootp;
authoritative;

ignore client-updates;
set vendorclass = option vendor-class-identifier;


subnet 10.100.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
      interface                         enp2s2f1;
      range                             10.100.0.10 10.100.0.200;
      default-lease-time                21600;
      max-lease-time                    43200;
      option subnet-mask                255.255.255.0;
      option broadcast-address          10.100.0.255;
      option routers                    10.100.0.1;
      option domain-name-servers        8.8.8.8;
      next-server                       10.100.0.1;
}
```

Firewalld rules :

```
[root@localhost dhcp]# firewall-cmd --list-all
internal (default, active)
  interfaces: enp2s2f1
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client dns http https ipp-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

And of course IPv4 forwarding is enbaled.

My problem is that if you look the result of ifconfig, enp2s2f1 doesn't get his static IP which is normally 10.100.0.1

I removed NetworkManager.

Internal PCs get IPs but i can't ping the router nor access internet.

Any ideas ???

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For enp2s2f1, Change:

```
TYPE="Bridge"
```

To:

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
```

Unless you want enp2s2f1 to be part of a bridge. If so, follow the [RHEL 7 instructions](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Network_Bridging_Using_the_Command_Line_Interface.html).